# I'm brewing hard cider - what can I do with the yeast afterward?

Tags: yeast

I currently have a largish bottle of cider fermenting away in my kitchen. I will rack it in the next weeks. I prepared the batch from mashed apples (not juice) and I expect some sediment of yeast and apple leftovers.

Any ideas what I can do with that? Any recipes that make use of this yeast?

I will store part of it for the next cider, but certainly not all. So I'm looking for other uses around the kitchen.

Comment: This might be better asking on the brewing site?  http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suppose you could make bread with it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried making bread once with leftover beer yeast.   It was the densest bread I've ever tasted.  Breadmaking not recommended.

You could try making vegemite.

> **How to make Vegemite.**
>
> Brewer's yeast is a good source of vitamin B, but live yeast tastes
>   boring, it is poorly digested. Inactivated yeast lacks the
>   disadvantages, but is still bland. The inventor of vegemite solved
>   this problem using autolysis: a process where the yeast's own enzymes
>   break it down.
>
> Spent brewer's yeast is sieved to get rid of hop resins, and washed to
>   remove bitter tastes. Then it is suspended in water at a temperature
>   greater than 37 C with no nutrients: the yeast cells die, and vitamins
>   and minerals leach out. Then the proteolytic (protein-splitting)
>   enzymes take over, breaking the yeast proteins down into smaller
>   water-soluble fragments, which also leach out. The yeast cell membrane
>   is unruptured during this time, and can be removed by centrifuging.
>   The clear light brown liquid is then concentrated under a vacuum to a
>   thick paste (the vacuum helps preserve flavours and vitamin B1,
>   thiamine). It is seasoned with salt, and a small proportion of celery
>   and onion extracts to increase the palatability.

From http://www.convictcreations.com/culture/foodwine.htm (Last section on page)

Comment: +1 for an axcuse to get a vaccuum distillation equipment.

Comment: also, this is the kind of answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Yeast is very nutritious.  You could probably figure out a way to give it some flavour and eat it.